# Erro ao enviar email: server response: 550 5.7.1 Must Authenticate

Tags: php, email

Estou tentando usar a função [mail()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php) do 
Porém, o seguinte aviso aparece quando rodo o script:

> " Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP
>   server response: 550 5.7.1 Must Authenticate!"

Como configuro isso?

Segue o código:

```
$message = "Blablablablablablabla";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()

$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

// Send

mail('gustavo.severo@marcoprojetos.com.br', 'Solicitação de Cadastro de Fornecedor de Serviço - Numero - 111 - Controladoria - Marco Projetos e Construções', $message);
```

Comment: poderia colocar o código na pergunta, para entendermos melhor?

Comment: Código postado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para previnir o abuso do envio de e-mail, mais conhecido como SPAM, muitos servidores pedem que o cliente esteja autenticado e seja legítimo.

A função `mail()` não consegue realizar essa autenticação, sendo assim é necessário utilizar uma outra biblioteca que suporte a autenticação por SMTP. (PEAR Mail, phpmailer, Swift Mailer, etc)

Se você tem um interesse, recomendo [esse](http://www.webartz.com.br/desenvolvimento-web/php/php-envio-de-e-mail-com-autenticacao-smtp/) ótimo tutorial para utilizar o PHPMailer.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094813/smtp-server-response-550-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-in-sending-email-to-a-non-comp)
[Fonte2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455469/authentication-php-mail)

Comment: eu baixei a classe PHPMailer e tentei rodar, mas dá um aviso de erro na classe SMTP... Se não me engano, diz que SMTP não existe ou não funciona :(

Comment: Qual o servidor de SMTP que você está utilizando? É o fornecido pelo servidor?

Comment: Do terra @Lucas. smtp.poa.terra.com.br e o mesmo exige autenticação.

Comment: Consegui rodar o phpmailer... Só parece que não está chegando no destinatário!
Eu estava apontando o riquire(phpmailer.php) do lugar errado. Valeu mesmo assim

Answer (score 0):

Alguns servidores não permitem que o campo `from` do email seja omitido. Ele é configurado como quarto argumento da função mail.

Configure ele da seguinte forma:

```
$headers = 'From: teste@seudominio.com' . PHP_EOL;
mail('gustavo.severo@marcoprojetos.com.br', 'titulo', $message, $headers);
```

Comment: o mesmo erro aparece.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem de construir e enviar os `headers` do seu email:

```
    $headers  = 'From: gustavo.severo@marcoprojetos.com.br'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: gustavo.severo@marcoprojetos.com.br'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'."\r\n";

    if(mail('gustavo.severo@marcoprojetos.com.br', 'Solicitação de Cadastro de Fornecedor de Serviço - Numero - 111 - Controladoria - Marco Projetos e Construções', $message, $headers)) 
        echo "Email enviado";
    else 
        echo "Ocorreu um erro no envio do email!";
```

Comment: estou recebendo o mesmo aviso: " Warning: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Must Authenticate!"

Comment: esse erro aparece na consola do seu browser? está a desenvolver localmente ou num servidor?

Comment: O aviso aparecer na tela.
Estou desenvolvendo local.

Comment: para desenvolver aplicativos de email localmente você precisa instalar e/ou configurar outros componentes para conseguir ultrapassar a restrições de autenticação. Aconselho que experimente carregar o seu código para um servidor e testar as funcionalidades de email aí.

Comment: Certo @CIRCLE, vou fazer isso.